# CSS: can't make all the links scroll horizontally running out the page width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontal scroll of all the links in the page, I have made them float horizontally but cannot make them scroll as the max-width of body is set to 100% (and it is necessary due to other elements of page!).

here is the markup:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="filters">
    <a data-filter="*">All</a>
    <a data-filters=".anim">animals</a>
    <a data-filters=".benc">benches and sofa</a>
    <a data-filters=".colu">columns and pillars</a>
    <a data-filters=".entr">entry gates</a>
    <a data-filters=".fire">fire places</a>
    <a data-filters=".flow">flower pot</a>
    <a data-filters=".foun">fountain</a>
    <a data-filters=".gaze">gazebo</a>
    <a data-filters=".jaal">jaalis and grills</a>
    <a data-filters=".ligh">light lamps</a>
    <a data-filters=".natu">natural planters</a>
    <a data-filters=".stat">statues</a>
    <a data-filters=".wash">wash basins</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and her is the css:

```
.header{
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header .filters{
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: fixed;
  width:auto;
  margin-top: 130px;
  max-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 17px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header .filters a{
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-family: LatoWebLight;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 150%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Also providing a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sameermanek/8rj2a8me/) for the same if you need!

I only need elements inside this div scrolling and not All the elements and the entire page!

Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had `width: auto` on the `.filter` element, which make the element grow with content and not create a scroll. I changed it to `width: 100%` and now it does scroll.

I also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to make the `padding: 17px 10px;` value be counted within the width.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header{
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header .filters {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 130px;
  max-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 17px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header .filters a{
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-family: LatoWebLight;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 150%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="filters">
    <a data-filter="*">All</a>
    <a data-filters=".anim">animals</a>
    <a data-filters=".benc">benches and sofa</a>
    <a data-filters=".colu">columns and pillars</a>
    <a data-filters=".entr">entry gates</a>
    <a data-filters=".fire">fire places</a>
    <a data-filters=".flow">flower pot</a>
    <a data-filters=".foun">fountain</a>
    <a data-filters=".gaze">gazebo</a>
    <a data-filters=".jaal">jaalis and grills</a>
    <a data-filters=".ligh">light lamps</a>
    <a data-filters=".natu">natural planters</a>
    <a data-filters=".stat">statues</a>
    <a data-filters=".wash">wash basins</a>
  </div>
</div>
```